# Problems with Interfaces and FactoryPattern

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, factory-pattern

I have created a factory pattern to create my objects, but each of the objects are slightly different and i want them to implement different methods, with my current setup I have to declare all methods in the interface and in the subsequent object classes, how can I get around this?

This is an example of the structure

food class

```
public class Food extends MyObjects implements MyActiveObject, {

public Food(String name, Coordinates coordinates, int size, Color color) {
    super(name, coordinates, size, color);  
    }
}
```

Herbivore class

```
public class Herbivore extends Entity implements MyActiveObject {
public Herbivore(String name,Coordinates coordinates, int size, Color color){
    super(name, coordinates, size, color);
}
```

}

interface

```
public interface MyActiveObject extends EntityInterface {

    public Coordinates getCoordinates();
    etc...
}
```

Factory class

```
public class MyActiveObjectFactory {

public MyActiveObject createObject(String objectType, int objectCount, int x, int y, int scale){

    if(objectType == null){
         return null;
    }else{

        if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("HERBIVORE")){
            return new Herbivore();
        }
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("CARNIVORE")){
            return new Carnivore();
        }
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("FOOD")){
            return new Food();
        }
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("DRINK")){
            return new Drink();
        }   
    }
    return null;
}
```

Object creation

```
MyActiveObject activeObject = activeObjectFactory.createObject("Herbivore", activeObjectCount, x, y, scale);
```

Ive removed any unessary code to save space, what im trying to do is store food and herbivore as an activeobject in an array but i want to be able to call different methods on each of them, I cannot change them to an abstract class due to the inheritence so im all out of ideas, can anyone help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but why can't you have something like this? The `getCoordinates` method is defined in the interface and implemented in each class, but each class also has its own methods.

```
public class Test{
    private MyActiveObject[] mObjList = new MyActiveObject[ 4 ];

    public Test(){
        mObjList[0] = new Food();
        mObjList[1] = new Drink();
        mObjList[2] = new Herbivore();
        mObjList[3] = new Carnivore();
    }

    public void doTest(){
        for( MyActiveObject obj : mObjList ){
            obj.getCoordinates();  // No conversion required for common method

            if( obj instanceof Herbivore ){
                Herbivore newObj = ( Herbivore ) obj;
                newObj.doHerbivoreWork();
            }
            else if( obj instanceof Carnivore ){
                Carnivore newObj = ( Carnivore ) obj;
                newObj.doCarnivoreWork();
            }
            else if( obj instanceof Food ){
                Food newObj = ( Food ) obj;
                newObj.doFoodWork();
            }
            else if( obj instanceof Drink ){
                Drink newObj = ( Drink ) obj;
                newObj.doDrinkWork();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        new Test().doTest();
    }
}
```

The `do<class>Word` methods contain just a print statement as do the `getCoordinates` methods. The output of running the above is:

```
Getting Food Coordinates...
Working on Foods.
Getting Drink Coordinates...
Working on Drinks.
Getting Herbivore Coordinates...
Working on Herbivores.
Getting Carnivore Coordinates...
Working on Carnivores.
```

**Update:** Here is the definition of the interface:

```
public interface MyActiveObject{
    public Coordinates getCoordinates();
}
```

The classes `Entity` and `MyObjects` are empty. `Drink` and `Food` extend `MyObjects`:

```
public class Drink extends MyObjects implements MyActiveObject{
    @Override
    public Coordinates getCoordinates(){
        System.out.println( "Getting Drink Coordinates..." );
        return new Coordinates();
    }
    public void doDrinkWork(){
        System.out.println( "Working on Drinks." );
    }
}
```

`Carnivore` and `Herbivore` extend `Entity`:

```
public class Carnivore extends Entity implements MyActiveObject{
    @Override
    public Coordinates getCoordinates(){
        System.out.println( "Getting Carnivore Coordinates..." );
        return new Coordinates();
    }
    public void doCarnivoreWork(){
        System.out.println( "Working on Carnivores." );
    }
}
```

**Update the second:**
I think I see the problem. The interface you are using has a lot of method signatures not needed in your classes. Is that it?

In that case, just create an empty marker interface just for the purpose of being able to place different classes in an array.

```
public interface Arrayable{};
```

Comment: Im not sure this will solve the problem, the factory pattern uses an interface for it to work which means i have to inherit all of the methods, the only way around this I found was to use an abstract factory pattern to split the interfaces and seperate the disimilar objects into their own lists(not something i wanted to do) but i cant find a way around the above problem, thank you for your post though, always appreciate the help :-)

Comment: If your problem is that the interface you are using has method signatures not needed in the classes, then see my second update. If that's not the problem, I am at a loss to understand the nature of your question. In that case, could you give a more detailed example of the problem?